# My android app is not visible in android market

Tags: android, google-play

I published my android app last week. Now The status of the app is active in the console and the details showing there is

**API level: 8-17+
Supported screens: small-xlarge
OpenGL textures: all**

But while searching the app in the market it is not visible.

My app content rating is **Everyone** and published in all countries.

In the Supported devices category it shows 1882 devices and it definitly includes My htc sensation too.

I tried with the link `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=MyPackage` (Got from stack) for finding my application but that time i am getting **We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.**

I am not getting the problem at all. Please help. What will happen if i unpublish and upload the application again ??

Please have a look on Manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="MyPackage"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
    android:label="@string/label"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity1"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <action android:name="android.speech.extra.RESULTS" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity3"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity4"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />


    <receiver
        android:name=".Receiver1"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="SMS" />
            <action android:name="REGISTERED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Add you manifest file code for estimating the problem?

Comment: @Kamalone I am having the similar issue can you tell me what helped at last

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

https://play.google.com/store/search?q=com.yourapp.appname&c=apps

The first time you upload your app it can take about 1 day before it is vissible in the Play Store, updates take about 1-12 hours. But lately it takes only about 2 hours!

Comment: Android Apps
About 3 results. getting like this.

But displays only one application

Comment: My app name is 55444. Please try

Comment: What's the package name? It must be something like com.google.gmail?

Comment: Is that also the exact value of 'package' in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Please go to: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/v2, after you click on your app check if there are no errors. Also check if you package name is the same

Comment: Yes Sir. It is same and there is no error. Status is published

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22957/discussion-between-obat-and-paru)